# Hamiltonian of the valence electron of Yb+ ion

Tags: quantum-state, experimental-realization, chemistry

Let's say I have chosen the valence electron of Yb+ as my qubit. I want to consider it's hyperfine structure as the two-level energy states.

Are my following assumptions correct?

1. If the magnetic moment of the electron is parallel to that of the nucleus, then the potential energy will be minimum
2. If the magnetic moment of the electron is anti-parallel to the nucleus, then the PE will be maximum
3. I can use a circularly polarized laser to create Rabi oscillations (should it be always circularly polarized light? why can't I use a linearly polarized laser)

Now, given this exact scenario, what will be the Hamiltonian of the electron so that I can solve for the SE?

Comment: What is the "SE"?  The Schroedinger equation? Or Stack Exchange? You're asking about the science of how hyperfine structure works, which is something that might be more appropriate on Physics.SE (where atomic physics and spectroscopy are on topic), Chemistry.SE (where spectroscopy is on topic), or MatterModeling.SE (where people model things like hyperfine structure). There seems to be nothing about quantum computing here other than the fact that you're *calling* the two-level system of hyperfine levels, a "qubit".